# How to insert HTML content stored in a filed in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, escape

I have stored HTML content in a custom field and I want to display the content in LWC. I can able to do this in visualforce page using below code.

```
<apex:outputtext value="{!longDescription}" escape="false"/>
```

How can I achieve this in LWC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lightning-formatted-rich-text`

```
<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={longDescription}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!. Its working fine

Comment: @Thirumagal Most welcome!!